# Getting error (800A0035) referencing a line of code that has already been executed

Tags: function, vbscript, wsh, filesystemobject, file-not-found

I am writing a script right now which makes use of the File System Object to read a text file and later delete it. The part of the code in which this occurs I have written as a function. I have tested this function, along with some other functions which it depends on, and it works fine. But in the final product it is just one part of a script with 16 different functions/subroutines. After incorporating it into the final product, this file fails to work. Or, at least Windows script host tells me that it doesn't.

I have tested using Echo statements to track down the issue, since the line that WSH references should have executed properly, based on the fact that code after the line in question works when I run the script. I get an Echo when I echo after the function call (I have written a simple function to make the script wait before calling more functions, and the echo statement is after that, so the function definitely completes execution before the error occurs). I have also tried inserting an echo statement into the beginning of the next function to be called (literally directly after I instantiate the second function), and then I don't get an echo.

Here is the function in question. The line the error references is the one with Set objRECID.

```
Function PullRecords
  Set objWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  strIP = "192.168.1.185"
  strOutFileCMD = ".output OUT" & strIP & ".txt"
  strOutFile = "C:\Users\" & GetLoggedOnUsername & "\Documents\SQLite3\" & "OUT" & strIP & ".txt"     'Output of each element grab
  strCommand = "FROM ZCDataField WHERE RECORD_ID="
  strRECIDPath = "C:\Users\" & GetLoggedOnUsername & "\Documents\SQLite3\" & "RECID" & strIP &     ".txt" 'Output of GetRECID
  strFinalCSVPath = "C:\Users\" & GetLoggedOnUsername & "\Documents\SQLite3\" & strIP & ".csv"
  strSQLite3Path = "C:\Users\" & GetLoggedOnUsername & "\Documents\SQLite3\"
  strProcName = "SQLite3.exe"

  'Element ID's (for reference)
  'intpt_item = "275426222"
  'intpt_description = "275466434"
  'intpt_custitem = "275466431"
  'intpt_qty = "275466713"
  'intpt_name = "275466710"
  'intpt_date = "275435183"
  'intpt_unixmil = "275578832"

  'Options for text files
  intForReading = 1
  intForWriting = 2
  intForAppending = 8
  boolOverwriteTrue = True
  boolOverwriteFalse = False

  Set objCSV = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFinalCSVPath,boolOverwriteTrue) 'Creates final CSV to be     written to/
  Set objRECID = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strRECIDPath,intForReading)

  'Cycles through records
  Do Until objRECID.AtEndOfStream
   strRECID = objRECID.ReadLine
   Set objELID = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSQLite3Path & "Element IDs.txt",intForReading) 'Need this      here so that script restarts at beginning of file each time.
   'Cycles through elements
   Do Until objELID.AtEndOfStream
    Set objBAT = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strSQLite3Path & strIP & dblUnixT &     ".bat",boolOverwriteTrue)
     objBAT.Write ("cd /D C:\Users\" & GetLoggedOnUsername & "\Documents\SQLite3")
     objBAT.WriteLine
     objBAT.Write ("sqlite3 " & strIP & ".db < " & strIP & ".txt")
    objBAT.Close

    Set objBAT = Nothing
    Set objCMDS = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strSQLite3Path & strIP & ".txt",boolOverwriteTrue)
     objCMDS.Write (".mode tabs")
     objCMDS.WriteLine
     objCMDS.Write (strOutFileCMD)
     objCMDS.WriteLine
     strELID = objELID.ReadLine  'Gets ELEMENT_ID
     objCMDS.Write ("SELECT VALUE_TXT,VALUE_NUM " & strCommand & strRECID & " AND ELEMENT_ID=" &     strELID &  ";") 'Gets element
     objCMDS.WriteLine   
     objCMDS.Write (".exit") 'Exits SQLite3
    objCMDS.Close
    Set objCMDS = Nothing   
    objWSH.Run(strSQLite3Path & strIP & dblUnixT & ".bat")


    'Makes script wait until BAT is done.
    intRunning  = 1
    Do Until intRunning = 0
     intRunning = IsRunning(strProcName)
    Loop

    Wscript.Sleep(500)

    Set objOut = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strOutFile)
    strOut = objOut.ReadLine
    objOut.Close
    Set objOut = Nothing
    objCSV.Write strOut & ","
    Loop
  'Make string of line and then delete 1 character on right to get rid of ,. Then replace line.  
   objCSV.Write Chr(8)
   objCSV.WriteLine
   objELID.Close
   Set objELID = Nothing
  Loop

  objCSV.Close
  objRECID.Close
  Set objCSV = Nothing
  Set objRECID = Nothing
  objFSO.DeleteFile strRECIDPath

  'objFSO.DeleteFile strOutFile

  InvertText(strFinalCSVPath)
  PullRecords = strFinalCSVPath

  Call FuncSubEndToken
End Function
```

In case it is useful, here is the FuncSubEndToken function that I call.

```
Function FuncSubEndToken
 intFuncSubEndToken = 1
End Function
```

And here is how I am using it when I call the PullRecords Function.

```
Call PullRecords
 'FuncSubEndTokenWait
 Do Until intFuncSubEndToken = 1
 Loop
 intFuncSubEndToken = 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have tried using On Error Resume Next and I just get wscript hanging after the parts that I posted. It doesn't even enter the next function.

Edit 2: I have tried commenting out the line that deletes the file that is needed for the PullRecords function, even though that line is executed after the function is done with the file. It now is apparent that is calling this function twice and another function twice (and then it errors out part way through that). I have looked and both of these functions are only ever called once (and they are not in loops, so that is definitely not the issue). I do call a function and pass it the output of both of these functions, in the order that they seem to be running. But I am not here calling the functions themselves. But perhaps wscript thinks that I am?

Edit 3: I have deleted the function that uses the return of the other two functions (well, commented it out), and I still get the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure the file you are trying to open with this line `Set objRECID = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strRECIDPath,intForReading)` actually exists?

Comment: Yes. I have tested the function that creates that file multiple times. I actually was getting some really weird permissions errors with that function yesterday. But I figured that out already. And the code after the OpenTextFile call wouldn't execute if it didn't exist anyway, since it would error out at the the OpenTextFile call. And I have both the echo statements and the visual evidence of a CMD window popping up from those later lines to confirm that the later lines of code do in fact execute.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: The line which you referred to is the one referenced by WSH. But there seems to be no way for that to be causing an error. Using echo statements I was able to figure out that the error does not occur until the first line of the function that follows the function I posted.

Comment: Thou shalt strive to always use [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to catch typos and other errors. Also, why use the `intRunning` loop instead of just passing True to the _bWaitOnReturn_ parameter of [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)?

Comment: When trying to use bWaitOnReturn wscript kept telling me that I was passing too many arguments to Run (even though I was only passing two). Since I know that bWaitOnReturn is fine for Run I decided to just give up on trying to figure that error out and use a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have now figured out the issue. It would seem that I was somewhat misinformed on how functions work when trying to get their output. I thought that you called a function and then the function name was the output. But, it would seem that you do not need to use a call statement to execute a function. So, while trying to use the output of my functions I have been inadvertently calling them.